# After The Order is placed it does not redirect to success page Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

After The Order is placed it does not redirect to success page instead it checkout/cart/ page with this message.
      SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY
      You have no items in your shopping cart.
      Click here to continue shopping.
And at the same time, the order is also placed but it did not redirect to the success page.

Currently, I am using Magento ver. 1.9.3.1
mbstring is also installed on my server.

Answer (score 0):

After placing the order some function call might taking too long to response or adding too much data to quote. My guess is that any observer function is looping. Check sales_order_place_after and other similar events. Hope that helps.